Switch flexbox containers on desktop and mobile with tailwind
I want to change the display and order of three components on screen resize. I've tried a few things with flexbox, but I'm not sure it's possible.
Essentially I want the components on mobile to appear like below. Image and title side by side with a description underneath:

and on desktop like below. Image on one side, with title and description together stacked:

Could anyone have a go at doing this using Tailwind?

You can achieve this with grid like so, the key player being row-span-2:
<div class="grid w-full max-w-xl grid-cols-2">
  <div class="flex h-full w-full items-center sm:row-span-2">
    <div class="flex aspect-square w-full items-center justify-center bg-red-400">
      image
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex aspect-square items-center justify-center bg-blue-400">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="flex aspect-square items-center justify-center bg-green-400">
    description
  </div>
</div>

You can check out the working example here.

I've edited the second image to make it clearer. It's not simply to change the description to the other side. It's for the desktop version to be two columns - one with the image, one with the title and description stacked.

@G.Cox I've updated my answer to accomodate your changes with a new snippet and working example.

Thanks @Rico. I had to tweak a couple things to work with the real components on my project, but using grid was the solution
